# Selecting data of 3d data set

Tags: list-manipulation

I have `x,y,z` positions of particles and corresponding velocities `vx,vy,vz`.

Example:

```
posdata = RandomReal[10, {100, 3}];
veldata = RandomReal[{-0.5, +0.5}, {100, 3}];
```

Now I want to select the all the positions and corresponding velocities inside a certain `x` interval.

If I want use e.g. `xmin=5` and `xmax=6`, then I could select all `x,y,z`-positions by:

```
pickedPositions=Pick[posdata, Unitize@Clip[posdata[[All, 1]], {5, 6}, {0, 0}], 1]
```

How can I find the corresponding velocity data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same selector array to pick from `veldata`:

```
pickedVelocities = Pick[veldata, Unitize@Clip[posdata[[All, 1]], {5, 6}, {0, 0}], 1]
```

Or you can do both in one step:

```
{pickedPos, pickedVel} = Transpose @ Pick[Transpose[{posdata, veldata}], 
   Unitize @ Clip[posdata[[All, 1]], {5, 6}, {0, 0}], 1];

And[pickedPos == pickedPositions, pickedVel == pickedVelocities]
```

> True

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Lenoil, my pleasure.